# Minimizing boolean algebra expressions

Tags: algorithm, karnaugh-map

I am trying to re-implement the BCD to 7-SEGMENT converter by hand. So, I have came up with the following truth table:

[image]

I have the following minimization created with the [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). Is there any way to minimize this more?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to minimize terms or gates?

Comment: gates and terms if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert it. Inverted logic often gives better results if there are more 1's than 0's.

When minimising gates also group similar subexpressions so they can share gates.

$$a = \overline{\overline{ABC}D + \overline{A}B\overline{CD} + A\overline{B}CD + AB\overline{C}D}\\
= \overline{\overline{AC}(\overline{B}D+B\overline{D}) + AD(\overline{B}C+B\overline{C})}\\
=[A+C+(B+\overline{D})(\overline{B}+D)][\overline{A}+\overline{D}+(B+\overline{C})(\overline{B}+C)]\\
=(A+C+\overline{BD}+BD)(\overline{A}+\overline{D}+\overline{BC}+BC)\\
=(A+C+\overline{B\oplus D})(\overline{A}+\overline{D}+\overline{B\oplus C})$$

Comment: but it doesn't work... below is a link to my circuit. the probe stays always on. http://imgur.com/mIW1kh7

Comment: Your circuit have several errors so it does not work. Upper XOR/OR is $A+\overline{C}+B\oplus D$ instead of $A+C+\overline{B\oplus D}$.